# Aligning texts and images in SwiftUI

Tags: swift, swiftui

The code below is from a simple SwiftUI ContentView.  It displays a piece of text and an image that I wish to have vertically aligned along their centre line.

```
var body: some View {
    HStack(alignment: .center) {
        Text("Cloudy")
            .background(Color.yellow)
        Image(systemName: "cloud.heavyrain")
            .background(Color.blue)
    }
    .font(.largeTitle)
    .border(Color.red)
}
```

Instead, I find that they appear to be centred on their frames.  For the text the frame is too big and for the image it is too small.

[image: Cloudy text and image]

Is it possible to align the contents (particularly the image - which seems to know no bounds) rather than the frames?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Images can have baselines, and although many times they are equal to zero, there are some other cases (like "Cloudy"), when they're not. If you set the baseline to zero, then it will center with the text:

```swift
struct ContentView: View {

    var body: some View {
        HStack(alignment: .center) {
            Text("Cloudy").background(Color.yellow)
            Image(uiImage: UIImage(systemName: "cloud.heavyrain")!.withBaselineOffset(fromBottom: 0))
                .background(Color.blue)
        }
        .font(.largeTitle)
        .border(Color.red)
    }
}
```

Comment: By the way, I also recommend you watch the **WWDC2019 session Introducing SF Symbols**.

Comment: Thanks for the reference to the WWDC session.  It was particularly enlightening.  I had assumed that SF Symbols was "just a font" and hadn't realised that it was such a significant part of the changes coming with SwiftUI.  It is, perhaps, unlucky that I had chosen weather symbols to attempt my first alignments since they appear to have a number of different baseline offsets. 

Your solution is a great improvement but changes the size of the rendered images.  I can see me spending the rest of the week learning the ins and outs of this system.

Comment: @kontiki this Only works for one line text , if the text is multiline then the image does not go exactly beside the text in the new line. Instead it is horizontally across with a padding to the right then the image for the new line

Comment: Now `.baselineOffset`, not `.withBaselineOffset`.